# Google line chart y axis border missing if begins with number greater than zero

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization, linechart, yaxis

I'm using Google Line chart to display some statistics. However, when the y axis value starts with a number greater than zero, the y-axis border(starting vertical border line) is missing. If the y-axis starts with zero, then I can see the axis border line. How to fix this issue when the value starts with number greater than zero? I want to show the axis border always.

Below shown is the code which I'm using to draw the line chart.

```js
  
  google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(prepareChartData);

function prepareChartData(){
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Total');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  title = 'My Chart';

  var options = {
title: title,
curveType: 'function',
legend: {position: 'bottom', alignment: 'start'},
colors: ['#003f5c', '#ffa600', '#665191', '#f95d6a'],
chartArea: {
    bottom: 80
},
annotations: {
  alwaysOutside: true,
  textStyle: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 11
  },
},
hAxis: {
  format: 'MMM yy',
  viewWindowMode: "explicit",
},
vAxis: {
  minValue: 0,
  viewWindowMode: "explicit",
  viewWindow: { min: 0 },
  title: ''
},
titleTextStyle: {
  color:'#3a3a3a',
  fontSize:24,
  bold:false
  // fontName: "Segoe UI"
  },
bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
bars: 'horizontal'
  };

  var chartDivId = "chart_div";
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartDivId));
  var rawData =[];

   var chart_object = { "Dec 19": {monthLabel: "Dec", chartArray:[{'date': "2019-12-31", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]},"Jan 20": {monthLabel: "Jan", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-1-01", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]},"Feb 20": {monthLabel: "Feb", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-2-29", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]}, "Mar 20": {monthLabel: "Mar", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-3-01", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"},{'date': "2020-03-12", 'total': "15", 'cats': "30", 'dogs': "30"}]}};

  $.each(chart_object, function(i, chartobject) {
    $.each(  chartobject.chartArray, function( chartIndex , chartValue ){

date = chartValue['date'];
total = parseInt(chartValue['total']);
catscount = parseInt(chartValue['cats']);
dogscount = parseInt(chartValue['dogs']);
catspercentage = 0;
catspercentageAnnotation = catscount+",  percent "+catspercentage+"%";
dogsspercentage = 0;
dogsspercentageAnnotation = dogscount+",  percent "+dogsspercentage+"%";

rawData.push([ new Date(date), total, {v: catscount, f: catspercentageAnnotation}, {v: dogscount, f: dogsspercentageAnnotation}]);
  });
  });

  var counter = 0;
  drawChart();

  function drawChart() {
if(counter < rawData.length){
  chartData.addRow(rawData[counter]);

  // build x-axis ticks to prevent repeated labels
  var dateFormat = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
  });
  var dateRange = chartData.getColumnRange(0);
  var ticks = [];
  var dateTick = dateRange.min;
  while (dateTick.getTime() <= dateRange.max.getTime()) {
    if (ticks.length === 0) {
      // format first tick
      ticks.push({
        v: dateTick,
        f: dateFormat.formatValue(dateTick)
      });
    } else {
      ticks.push(dateTick);
    }
    dateTick = new Date(dateTick.getFullYear(), dateTick.getMonth() + 1, 1);
  }
  options.hAxis.ticks = ticks;

  chart.draw(chartData, options);
  counter++;
  window.setTimeout(drawChart, 1000);
}
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this line is referred to as the baseline.
by default, the baseline is zero.
you can change the baseline to any number.

to display, set the baseline to the same number as the min axis value.

```
vAxis: {
  viewWindow: { min: 2 },
  baseline: 2,
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(prepareChartData);

function prepareChartData(){
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Total');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  title = 'My Chart';

  var options = {
title: title,
curveType: 'function',
legend: {position: 'bottom', alignment: 'start'},
colors: ['#003f5c', '#ffa600', '#665191', '#f95d6a'],
chartArea: {
    bottom: 80
},
annotations: {
  alwaysOutside: true,
  textStyle: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 11
  },
},
hAxis: {
  format: 'MMM yy',
  viewWindowMode: "explicit",
},
vAxis: {
  viewWindowMode: "explicit",
  viewWindow: { min: 2 },
  baseline: 2,
  title: ''
},
titleTextStyle: {
  color:'#3a3a3a',
  fontSize:24,
  bold:false
  // fontName: "Segoe UI"
  },
bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
bars: 'horizontal'
  };

  var chartDivId = "chart_div";
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartDivId));
  var rawData =[];

   var chart_object = { "Dec 19": {monthLabel: "Dec", chartArray:[{'date': "2019-12-31", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]},"Jan 20": {monthLabel: "Jan", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-1-01", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]},"Feb 20": {monthLabel: "Feb", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-2-29", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"}]}, "Mar 20": {monthLabel: "Mar", chartArray:[{'date': "2020-3-01", 'total': "5", 'cats': "10", 'dogs': "10"},{'date': "2020-03-12", 'total': "15", 'cats': "30", 'dogs': "30"}]}};

  $.each(chart_object, function(i, chartobject) {
    $.each(  chartobject.chartArray, function( chartIndex , chartValue ){

date = chartValue['date'];
total = parseInt(chartValue['total']);
catscount = parseInt(chartValue['cats']);
dogscount = parseInt(chartValue['dogs']);
catspercentage = 0;
catspercentageAnnotation = catscount+",  percent "+catspercentage+"%";
dogsspercentage = 0;
dogsspercentageAnnotation = dogscount+",  percent "+dogsspercentage+"%";

rawData.push([ new Date(date), total, {v: catscount, f: catspercentageAnnotation}, {v: dogscount, f: dogsspercentageAnnotation}]);
  });
  });

  var counter = 0;
  drawChart();

  function drawChart() {
if(counter < rawData.length){
  chartData.addRow(rawData[counter]);

  // build x-axis ticks to prevent repeated labels
  var dateFormat = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
  });
  var dateRange = chartData.getColumnRange(0);
  var ticks = [];
  var dateTick = dateRange.min;
  while (dateTick.getTime() <= dateRange.max.getTime()) {
    if (ticks.length === 0) {
      // format first tick
      ticks.push({
        v: dateTick,
        f: dateFormat.formatValue(dateTick)
      });
    } else {
      ticks.push(dateTick);
    }
    dateTick = new Date(dateTick.getFullYear(), dateTick.getMonth() + 1, 1);
  }
  options.hAxis.ticks = ticks;

  chart.draw(chartData, options);
  counter++;
  window.setTimeout(drawChart, 1000);
}
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried adding min and baseline but still its not showing the starting border line for vertical line.

Comment: will you please edit the question with the latest attempt?